# Using of a4j:commandLink; how it works?

Tags: ajax, jsf, richfaces

In my project I have the facelet, which contains the following chunk of markup:

```
<rich:column sortable="true" sortBy="#{item.date}">
    <a4j:commandLink value="#{item.dateView}"
                     reRender="reportTable">
    <a4j:actionparam name="shown" value="#{not item.showDetails}"
                            assignTo="#{item.showDetails}" />
    </a4j:commandLink>
</rich:column>
```

After I've clicked to the `commandLink` I have that my table is reRendered with an additional data. But I completely don't undertand how it works. I've read a [corresponding manual page](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/html/a4j_commandLink.html) about one, but it is still not clear. In the manual's example we use the following tag:

```
<a4j:commandLink value="Get greeting" reRender="greeting" />
```

And after we've clicked to it we get a message `"Hello %name%"`. Where is the String template for the `"Hello %name%"` message is located. In the other word, I would like to enquire where the data that I reRendered is located?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`a4j:commandLink` assigns (boolean) value of `!item.showDetails` into `item.showDetails` and re-render `reportTable`. Your additional data (which you see after click to command link) is displayed after re-rendering  of table, because there is (probably rendering) condition similar to `"#{item.showDetails}"`.